# How do i save each letter of string in different array position ? and combine back to single string?

Tags: javascript

I am making simple game, planning on using the Fisher–Yates Shuffle to scramble a word.

How do i populate array with each letter of the string ? And after the algorithm has finished how do i fill in the string with the scrambled word ?

For the second part I can imagine it will be just loop through the array and add the current array position content to the string but not sure what the code would look like.

I am not very experienced with javascript i understand if this is bit of a broad question.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
var str = "A long string here...",
var lettersArray = str.split(''); //["A", " ", "l", "o", "n", "g", " ", "s", "t", "r", "i", "n", "g", " ", "h", "e", "r", "e", ".", ".", "."]
//Doing some stuff here...
var scramble = lettersArray.join('')); //"A long string here..."
```

Comment: thanks i will give it a go. Would you mind explaining what the console.log means ? could i use something like var scramble = lettersArray.join('')); ?

Comment: Yes you can use ` var scramble = lettersArray.join(''));` you don't need `console.log`. I'm just printing the whole string. I'll edit my answer and remove `console.log` to be more clear.

Answer (score 2):

//Using Fisher-Yates:

```
function scrambleWord(word){
    var A= word.split(''),
    i, temp, L= A.length;
    while(--L){
        i= Math.floor(Math.random()*L);
        temp= A[i];
        A[i]= A[L];
        A[L]= temp;
    }
    return A.join('');
}

var alpha= 'supercalifragelisticexpialadocious';
scrambleWord(alpha);

/*  returned value: (String)
xgitellpcuecpuraaiasrideloiasfscio
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be simply achieved by using [String.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [Array.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
See example on js [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/CBWWW/)
This code will split the string into an array and then return the array content to a string with the characters in original order.

```
var string = "hocus pocus",
    array = string.split(""),
    newString = array.join("");

alert(newString);
```

In ECMAScript6 (Harmony) there is also a new method called [String.toArray](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3astring_extras)

I don't believe any [current browsers](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/es6/) support it.

A [shim](https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim) is already available for this so that you can start using this syntax right away, should you want to.

Just an interesting note of up and coming features.